# Cakephp 2 Form Helper

Tags: cakephp-2.0, form-helpers

How do I produce the following HTMl using the Cakephp form helper:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input-Default" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Default</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-Default">
</div>
</div>
```

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in the Html helper.

```
echo $this->Html->div('form-group',
    $this->Html->tag('label', 'Default',
        array(
            'for' => 'input-Default',
            'class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label',
        )
    ) .
    $this->Html->div('col-sm-10',
        $this->Form->input('',
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'id' => 'input-Default',
                'div' => false,
                'label' => false
            )
        )
    )
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html